# How spring bind beans scope with HTTP scope like request,session etc

Tags: java, spring, web

We have spring beans like:

```
@Component
@Scope(value="session")
public class MyBean {
    // ...
}
```

How internally spring bind the HTTP scopes like request, session with corresponding bean's scope. Is there any role of `RequestContextListener` for this?

Answer (score -1):

RequestContextListener will bind the HTTP request object to the Thread that is servicing that request. This makes beans that are request and session scoped available for further down the call chain.

Even DispatcherServlet and RequestContextFilter will do exactly the same thing

Comment: Can you little bit elaborate in a pseudo-code manner.Or provide any links which have those details.